# Oracle Advanced Security Options is Blank

Tags: oracle

I just installed Oracle DB 10gR2 with Oracle Advanced Security, but cannot see the algorithms.

> [user@db-1] adapters
>      Installed Oracle Net transport protocols are:
>       IPC
>       BEQ
>       TCP/IP
>       SSL
>       RAW

```
Installed Oracle Net naming methods are:

Local Naming (tnsnames.ora)
Oracle Directory Naming
Oracle Host Naming
Oracle Names Server Naming

Installed Oracle Advanced Security options are:
```

Where are all the algorithms for Oracle Advanced Security options please?

I checked the $ORACLE_HOME/bin/adapters file and it's looking for naea256i, naemd5i, etc. in the naetab.so file, but none of these are listed in the naetab.so file. What's wrong with the naetab.so file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Oracle Advanced Security Administrator's Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asointro.htm#sthref81), Oracle Advanced Security Architecture for a pretty nice graphical overview.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I did.

### Answer

Install Oracle Database Enterprise Edition. For example, use the ee.rsp response file, not the standard.rsp response file.